# Automatically my laptop types +++++++ symbol in all search box

Tags: windows

I use dell inspiron 15 3521 and os is win8. For three days whenever i start my laptop the search option came and began to type +++++++++++++++++. When i press windows key, magnifier opens and disturbes me. I can't type any documents or any file/folder name. I scanned with Kaspersky and bitdefender... but no use. I uninstalled key board driver.. now key board is off, but still same problems happen... This is not a key problem..

please anyone help to solve this...

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you are in some kind of Accessibility mode. Try holding the CTRL key for about 15 seconds, which should popup a dialog for the Windows accessibility service.  Check that it's turned off.

Otherwise, are you seeing it type +++++++ in other windows, such as Notepad? Is it possible your + key is broken?

Comment: also note: when checking if your plus key is broken, you will be checking the one on the extended number pad. (the regular plus button requires the shift key to be pressed at the same time, otherwise it is equals)